# Excel: DEC2HEX() wrong conversion !? How to fix or any other solution?

Tags: excel, hex, decimal

**The idea is to add hours to date time and convert to HEX.**

I have the following table:

[image]

In **column B** i put the hours to add 
In **column C** i use formula: **=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))+B3/24** , to calculate the new time 
In **column D** i use formula: **=(C3-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400** , to calculate the timestamp 
In **column E** i use formula: **="0x"&DEC2HEX(D3)** , to convert timestamp to HEX

**The problem:**

When converts D3 (timestamp) with DEC2HEX it's incorrect, but the other ones are OK (on the snipet) !

0x59DC6FEF = 10/10/2017 06:59:59 
0x59DC6FF0 = 10/10/2017 07:00:00

What is the solution ? I need to have correct conversions, that 1 second counts too

Comment: Why would you need to have datetime in hex?  Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish your end goal, whatever it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some sort of rounding issue, the result in D3 is deemed to be very slightly below the actual value shown - try using `ROUND` function in column D, e.g.

`=ROUND((C3-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400,0)`